# Change XML node attribute value via WCF servive

Tags: c#, .net, xml, wcf, xmldocument

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IParametersXMLService
{
    [OperationContract, XmlSerializerFormat]
    XmlNode GetCommonNode(string path);

    [OperationContract, XmlSerializerFormat]
    void SetCommonNode(string path, string value);
}
```

Service implementation:

```
    public XmlNode GetCommonNode(string path)
    {
        XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
        xml.Load(path);
        XmlNode node = (XmlNode)xml.DocumentElement;
        XmlNode commonNode = node.SelectSingleNode("/blabla/att);
        return commonNode;
    }

    public void SetCommonNode(string path, string value)
    {
        XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
        xml.Load(path);
        XmlNode node = (XmlNode)xml.DocumentElement;
        XmlNode commonNode = node.SelectSingleNode("/blabla/att");
        commonNode.Attributes["List"].Value = value;
    }
```

`GetCommonNode` works fine and returns my value.
`SetCommonNode` does not change my value.
Maybe I need to save this file after change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As indicated, you seem to be missing the XML Document save method call.
You should be able to resolve the issue by adding the following:

```
xml.Save(path);
```

The following link provides additional details:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301233